# Illegal offset type (View: /code/resources/views/emergencia/nuevo.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I work with `multi-select`, and the result of one depends on the other. The controller is working.
Here is my model:

```
public static function getRegionesWithComunasOptGroup($comunas = null) {
  $data = array();

  if ($comunas == null) {
     $regiones = Region::all();//getRegionesUserLoggedIn();
     foreach ($regiones as $key => $value) {
       $data[$value] = DatosComunaProvinciaRegion::where('estado_comuna', '=', '1')->where('id_region_fk', $key)->whereIn('id_comuna', UsuarioComuna::pluck('id_comuna_fk'))->pluck('nmb_comuna', 'id_comuna');
     }
  }
```

Here it's my blade:

```
{{ Form::select('comunas[]', App\Region::getRegionesWithComunasOptGroup(), old('funcion'),
array('id' => 'funcion', 'class' => 'multiselect form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'multiple' => 'multiple')) 
}}
```

Comment: You don't state which line generates the error, but maybe `$value` is an array or object?

Comment: What does `var_dump($value);` show?